# Browser sandbox

Tags: browser, sandbox

Would running a browser in a sandbox environment prevent viruses/spyware? Will this session be considered secure & anonymous?

**EDIT**: I use [SPOON](http://www.spoon.net/browsers/) & my question is based on this browser plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would running a browser in a
>   sandbox environment prevent
>   viruses/spyware?

While nothing is 100% impenetrable, browsing the interwebs inside a sandbox is much safer than outside.

> Will this session be considered secure
>   & anonymous?

A sandbox isn't necessarily about anonymity, unless you delete the sandbox and wipe the free space after using it (or run the sandbox through a RAM disk).

Comment: @Molly - Are you saying even when using a browser sandbox plugin like Spoon, it isn't anonymous?

Answer (score 2):

I can't guarantee you that it's anonymous, but Sandboxie should be able to do the trick

http://sandboxie.com/

Comment: thanks but i am specifically asking about spoon browser plugin. Please see my updated question.